# Holo Theme For EditText In dialog

Tags: android, view, themes, android-edittext

I have a dialog which has 2 edit text in it a title and comment ..i want this edittext in holo theme .please anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new 
ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom));
```

Becoz android uses ContextThemeWrapper to style the dialog.

Make sure to define your custom style in the resources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme_Holo_Dialog">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

You can get more themes here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html

Comment: Yes thanks for the info but im not uusing alertdialog..
I have a class which extends dialog. so in this dialog i represent edittext which i want in holo theme.But what can i do if i use dilog?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: okay..i have an activity x which has a button onclick of it opens an dialog with edittext. i have created a class  by extending a Dialog for the diloag..now i want the edittext in holo theme.. hope i make myself clear!!

Comment: Why do you extend Dialog? it is not required to extend Dialog when u want to show dialogs in your activity. Don't extend Dialog and use AlertDialog.Builder it gets the job done. refer this link: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-alertdialog-your-android-application